# Why I get error when trying to open the dropdown list in a combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, mismatch, vba

I get a mismatch error when trying to open the dropdown list in a combobox in a userform

I've read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx
(Didn't understand it.)

**The sub that gets the error**

```
Private Sub FailureComBox_DropButtonClick()

Dim emptyRow As Long, i As Integer

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Fel").Range("A:A")) + 1

For i = 2 To emptyRow
    FailureComBox.AddItem Cells(i, "A")
Next i

End Sub
```

I get an mismatch error on the line that reads:
`FailureComBox.AddItem Cells(i, "A")`

**My entire code for the userform**

```
Private Sub BackCB_Click()

Unload Me
UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub ExitCB_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub FailureComBox_Change()

FailureComBox.Text = FailureComBox.Value

End Sub

Private Sub FailureComBox_DropButtonClick()

Dim emptyRow As Long, i As Integer

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Fel").Range("A:A")) + 1

For i = 2 To emptyRow
    FailureComBox.AddItem Cells(i, "A")
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub OkCB_Click()


Dim emptyRow As Long

emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

If IsDate(DateTB) = False Then
    MsgBox "Var vänlig ange ett korrekt datum"

ElseIf FailureComBox <> "" And StopComBox <> "" Then
    MsgBox "Var vänlig välj bara ett stopp eller fel."
    
Else
    
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = DateTB.Value
    
    If SLD000OB = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = SLD00OB.Caption
    
    If SLD00OB = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = SLD00OB.Caption
        
    If SLD1OB = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = SLD1OB.Caption
        
    If SLD2OB = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = SLD2OB.Caption

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works perfect for me. No fails. When do you exactly call this code?

Comment: When i click the dropdown arrow on the combobox to load the added items.

Comment: I do that and it works perfect, so you must have another code that makes this one crash. Try debugging your code. Does the code start the loop you have? What is the value of i when it fails? And also, most important, **make sure ALL CELLS in Range ("A:A") are not errors (NULL!, #REF!, #DIV/0!,and so on)**

Comment: All cells are filled with proper text

Comment: What is the value of i when it fails?

Comment: The cell is A2 and the value is "Fett på paletten"

Comment: Are you sure of that? Your code works 100% perfect for me. Value of i is 2?

Comment: Yes, when I hover with the cursor over the code in debugg mode it says that anyways. That text is only located in that across the entire workbook.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt project, corrupt environment or both. Save your code to notepad then reboot (cold start) the computer. If that doesn't fix it then rebuild your project from the notepad save

Comment: what happens if you change `For i=3`?

Comment: The restart worked with the original document. Now it displays the values correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim a As String

For i = 3 To emptyRow
    FailureComBox.AddItem a
    a = Sheets("StopFel").Cells(i, "D")
Next i
```

This fixed it for me. apparently `.AddItem` got a problem with setting a cell directly as its value.